# jQuery: Trouble inserting DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I want to add a set of lists to the children of another DOM element:

```
    var req_subsets = $("#req_subsets");

    $.each(subsets, function(index, subset) {

        var subset_list = $("<ul></ul>");

        // add DOM elements to subset_list

        req_subsets.append(subset_list);
    });
```

However, only one DOM element is ever added. This makes me suspect that when I assign a new value to `subset_list`, the old one is overwritten. If that is the problem, how do I avoid it? If not, what else am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:** I changed something else, and I'm almost entirely certain that this is fixed.

Comment: We need to know what the value of `subsets` is in your call to `$.each()` before we can help.

Comment: What you suspect is a problem is not the problem. Each time the callback is called you are creating a new DOM element.  The first thing to look at is the size of subsets.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend using [Easy DOM Creation](http://mg.to/2006/02/27/easy-dom-creation-for-jquery-and-prototype) for this kind of things

but you can try this anyway
fixed:

```
var req_subsets = $("#req_subsets");

$.each(subsets, function(index, subset) {

    var subset_list = $("<ul></ul>");

    // add DOM elements to subset_list

    subset.append(subset_list);
});
```